# MongoDB issue referencing schema design

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm looking to define a MongoDB User schema.

If I create a User collection where I set the validation, I then want to specify in the schema that a organisationId field references to a Organisation object in the organisation collection.

How do I go about achieving this?

I understand that Mongo should not be used this way, but at this time, this is essential. Using mongoose is not an option.

Expected ->

```js
db.createCollection('users') 

// Where users has set validation organisationId: Object(Organisation)
```

Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validator for this!
for example:

```js
db.createCollection("students", {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name", "year", "major", "address" ],
         properties: {
            name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            year: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            major: {
               enum: [ "Math", "English", "Computer Science", "History", null ],
               description: "can only be one of the enum values and is required"
            },
            gpa: {
               bsonType: [ "double" ],
               description: "must be a double if the field exists"
            },
            address: {
               bsonType: "object",
               required: [ "city" ],
               properties: {
                  street: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     description: "must be a string if the field exists"
                  },
                  city: {
                     bsonType: "string",
                     "description": "must be a string and is required"
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: In this case there is not reference to another collection in the db.